# Iterate through collection of List<object>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-grid

I have what is probably  simple problem, but I am stumped.  I call a method from another assembly that returns me a `List<object>`, this data is Excel spreadsheet data queried using `LinqToExcel`.  Under the scenes, that collection is actually a `List<LinqToExcel.Cell>`.  In `LinqToExcel`, that makes up a `LinqToExcel.Row`.  I want to be able to bind this data to a Telerik ASP.NET MVC grid for viewing.  Here's my controller code:

```
TypeOfServiceCodeListingDetailViewModel model = new TypeOfServiceCodeListingDetailViewModel();
model.Excel_Data = new List<LinqToExcel.Row>();
using (LinqToExcelReader reader = new LinqToExcelReader(fileName, true))
{
  previewData = reader.ReadRawDataByPage(5, 0);

  foreach (LinqToExcel.Row item in previewData)
  {
    model.Excel_Data.Add(item);
  }
  return View(new GridModel(model.Excel_Data));  
}
```

And in my view:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Excel_Data)
                .Name("Grid2")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:400px;" })
                .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("GetExcelData", "TypeOfService"))
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                  columns.AutoGenerate(column =>
                  {
                    column.Width = "150px";
                  });
                }))
```

Here's what my grid has headers like the below with no data:

Capacity           Count

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that solved my problem.  I'm sure there's a better approach.

```
using (LinqToExcelReader reader = new LinqToExcelReader(modelDetail.FileName, true))
{
  var previewData = reader.ReadRawDataByPage(5, 0);

  List<List<string>> masterList = new List<List<string>>();

  for (int x = 0; x < previewData.Count; x++)
  {
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    foreach (var cell in (LinqToExcel.Row)previewData[x])
    {
      list.Add(cell);
    }

    masterList.Add(list);
  }

  var listTest = masterList;
  modelDetail.ExcelData = new List<ExcelData>();

  foreach (List<string> theList in masterList)
  {
    ExcelData xlsData = new ExcelData();
    xlsData.Column1 = theList[0];
    xlsData.Column2 = theList[1];
    xlsData.Column3 = theList[2];
    xlsData.Column4 = theList[3];
    xlsData.Column5 = theList[4];
    xlsData.Column6 = theList[5];
    xlsData.Column7 = theList[6];
    xlsData.Column8 = theList[7];
    xlsData.Column9 = theList[8];
    xlsData.Column10 = theList[9];

    modelDetail.ExcelData.Add(xlsData);
  }
```